# Can not resolve symbol factory

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to integrate segment.io in my app. I was following the steps on the official site.

```
 Analytics.Builder builder = new Analytics.Builder(this, ANALYTICS_WRITE_KEY);
    builder.use(GoogleAnalyticsIntegration.FACTORY);
    builder.use(BranchIntegration.FACTORY);
```

I am getting the following error FACTORY can not resolve and error in BranchIntegration. Can anybody please tell me why I am getting this error.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
 compile 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.+'
// google analytics dependency for segment.io
compile('com.segment.analytics.android:analytics-integration-google-analytics:+') {
    transitive = true
}
```